# Как отключить в Google Dev Tools объединение селекторов через запятую?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Как (и можно ли) отключить в Dev Tools Хрома автоматическое объединение через запятую селекторов с одинаковыми свойствами?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]